# Unable to Discover Devices on Bluetooth in android 6.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I used this code and this ran in my older android phone [android 4.0]
but when i use the same set of code for android 6.1 , its not functioning properly , **it is not able to discover nearby blue tooth devices due to some reasons in newer android version. I am assuming its because they changed some security permissions after android 6.0** , can someone tell me what do i do to make this code run on both newer and older devices to discover nearby blue tooth devices ?I have given the following permissions also in the android manifest "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","android.permission.BLUETOOTH","android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" ,"android.permission.INTERNET" Also i have doubts if i am supposed to use the Bluetooth Le because this code is discarded by newer android versions ?
The code's part is given below

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter;
Button bton;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insidelogin);
    ......
    ......

    adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    ......
    ......

    bton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bton);
    bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    int z=1;
    if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
          z = 0;
          scan.setText("TURN BLUETOOTH ON FIRST");
            }

          if(z==1){

                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
                                                        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
                registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
                adapter.startDiscovery();

            }



        }
    });     
}
```

Then in Broadcast Reciever in OnReceive i have the follow code

```
String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
       //discovery starts, we can show progress dialog or perform other task                 
        }

        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))                    
           {
            scan.setText("scan FinN");
            if(z==1) {
                adapter.startDiscovery();
            }

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            //bluetooth device found
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice)          
            intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String s = device.getName();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            device.getAddress()+"  "+device.getName(),                 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just because you define the permission in your manifest does not mean you have the permission. Go to settings -> Applications -> your app and make sure the permission is turned on. Or use something like `public static boolean isPermissionGranted(Context context, String permission){
        boolean isPermissionGranted = false;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            isPermissionGranted = true;
        }
        return isPermissionGranted;
    }`  where permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION